# ssh firefox endless connection, even when the ssh connection is closed

Tags: firefox, ssh, putty, nohup

I want to build a connection to a server with the help of ssh and run firefox(reload website with the addon ReloadEvery).

Up to here I got it to work.

Now the next step would be to close the PuTTY(SSH-connection) and to make sure that the session is still running on the server I was logged in to.

Therefore I already tried:

-ssh firefox &
-nohup
-several scripts

would love to hear some ideas from you guys
thanks

Comment: What specifically goes wrong? Original SSH doesn't close? You can't run those commands? Or the commands don't produce what is expected?

Comment: i want to shut down my connection and run firefox in the background on the server i was logged into. It should refresh itself every minute.

Comment: the problem is that the process is terminating when i shut down the ssh connection

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/285015/linux-prevent-a-background-process-from-being-stopped-after-closing-ssh-client might help. The important thing is to redirect all streams. Make sure you redirect the remote streams, not the local ones.

Comment: nevertheless I've noticed this thread. I have a process running since 6 hours , which is only a shell script that is doing some nope. But I can't get it running with firefox, I think it has something to do with X forwarding

Comment: The problem is that X-Windows clients require a X-Windows server to display. When that connection goes away, it is the same as clicking the 'X' button in the window's decoration. I believe there was some experimentation on getting a X client to switch between X servers, but I don't believe it was working properly.                                                           I also tried w3m console browser, but it does not meet my needs

Comment: Hmm... you say, "when that connection goes away"? You mean, you run FF connecting it with X through the ssh channel?!

That means, you need to create FF remotely and in such a way that it doesn't connect to X through X redirection but through the X's native channel at the remote machine.

See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584411/how-to-run-an-x-program-from-outside-the-x-session-e-g-from-the-console-or-ssh on how to do that. Do disable X redirection before trying.